# What happens if there is a mistake/more things wanted when submitting naturalization

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, nationality

We are submitting our kids naturalization papers before brexit on December 31. From where I came from e.g. Pakistan if papers(visa) are refused or missing items, they send the paper back while not refunding the money. I do not know if that is the case e.g. if something is wrong/they added more documents (if required), will they refund it or will 2k goes to waste?

The reason I am not applying through lawyer as they are asking a lot and I lost job due to CVOID-19.

Answer (score 1):

- You will not get a refund if your application is refused or withdrawn.
- If the full fee or biometric data is not provided, then the application will be rejected as invalid. The application will not be considered and the fee will be refunded less an administration fee of £25.

Other fees and the refund terms applicable are explained here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/fees-for-citizenship-applications/fees-for-citizenship-applications-and-the-right-of-abode-from-6-april-2018

Comment: Thank you. We got everrything right but I see 2 problem that they might raise, my first name is my sons middle name and the field says "surname and first name". Same is on Birth cert. so we put it as part of surname, and other issue is the doctor as refree is an family friend who is a doctor as well so we put him as family doctor, who lives 300 miles away (south and north)  so they might ask why is ur family doctor so far? in those two cases, will they refuse or ask to clarify?

Comment: It’s quite unclear if an application is “rejected” if things are missing, or if they just put the decision on hold until missing things are supplied or questions have been cleared up.